# Given a written repartition function i want to decide what will be the first item

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy

I wrote the following function in python witch returns the weights of a power distribution

```py
import math
def get_power_distribution(distribution_count=8, power_distribution=1.3):
    repartition = [math.pow(power_distribution, i + 1) for i in range(distribution_count)]
    repartition_sum = sum(repartition)
    distribution = [val / repartition_sum for val in repartition]
    return distribution
```

It powers `1`^`power_distribution` to `distribution_count`^ `power_distribution`, sums all results and then tells what part of sum each power represents.

The returned distribution sums equals 100%, 1.0

```py
res=get_power_distribution(3,10)
[0.009009009009009009, 0.09009009009009009, 0.9009009009009009]
sum(res)
1.0
```

I want to decide what will be the first item of the returned list
Instead of having 0.009009009009009009 as res[0] **i would like to compute what `power_distribution` would have gave me `0.01` with this `distribution_count`**

The new signature of the function could then be

```
def get_power_distribution(distribution_count=8, start=0.01):
```

```py
res=get_power_distribution(3,0.01)
[0.01, y, z]
sum(res)
1.0
```

> Solving it with sympy or scipy seems possible .

i think of something like this :

```py
def base_to_power(target,distib_count):
    from sympy import symbols, solve
    x = symbols('x')
    expr = x * sum([x**(i+1) for i in range(distib_count)]) - target # Exact opposite of res[0] from get_power_distribution
    res = solve(expr)
    return res
```

Comment: What about using `round(res[0], 2)`?

Comment: The sum would not be 1.0, thus it would not be a distribution

Comment: If the count is 3, you would need to solve the 3rd order polynomial `Nx^3+Nx^2+(1-N)x = 0`, where N is your target of 0.01.  There are ways to solve 3rd order polynomials, but if count is bigger than 3, the iterative solution would be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You could either write your own bisection routine to bisect a function like

```py
def bisect(f, lo, hi, dif):
    if hi < lo:
        hi, lo = lo, hi
    a = f(lo)
    b = f(hi)
    while a*b < 0 and hi-lo > dif:
        m = (lo + hi)/2
        c = f(m)
        if c*f(hi) < 0:
            a = c
            lo = m
        else:
            b = c
            hi = m
    return m
```

Then

```
>>> f = lambda x: get_power_distribution(3, x)[0] - 0.01
>>> lo=1;hi=10,tol=0.01;bisect(f, (lo, hi), tol)
9.4609375
```

Or you could write your function to allow for symbolic input (ala SymPy) and then use the existing `nsolve`: change `math.pow` to `sympy.Pow` and import sympy instead of math.

```py
>>> nsolve(f(x), (1, 10), solver='bisect', prec=3)
9.46
```

If you use the symbolic form, you can also obtain a polynomial in `x` that you would like to solve. Since it will have an order 1 less than the count, there may not be a closed form solution but you can easily evaluate the root (iteratively) to whatever precision you desire. The part that is not iterative is the creation of the expression to be solved, e.g.

```py
def g(t, n):
    eq = get_power_distribution(n, x)[0] - nsimplify(t, rational=True)
    pos = [i for i in real_roots(eq.as_numer_denom()[0]) if i.is_positive]
    assert len(pos) == 1
    return pos[0]
>>> g(.01, 3)
-1/2 + sqrt(397)/2
>>> _.n(3)
9.46
>>> g(2/5, 4)
CRootOf(2*x**3 + 2*x**2 + 2*x - 3, 0)
>>> _.n(3)
0.961
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I try to solve it in a mathematical way instead of using an iteration. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/solving/solve-equation-algebraically.html

Comment: maybe like that :
from sympy import symbols, solve
x = symbols('x')
expr = x * sum([x**(i+1) for i in range(distib_count)]) - cible
res = solve(expr)

Comment: That's still iterative.

Comment: I added another suggestion.